# Facebook SDK for Unity FB.AppRequest does not respect screen orientation on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook SDK for Unity FB.AppRequest does not respect screen orientation on iOS

I've tried with version 6.0 and 6.1beta, and both have the same issue.

My app is landscape (allows for both landscape orientations), what's really strange is the dialog (FB.AppRequest) pops up in Upside Down Portrait orientation, and then, when you try to search for a friend, the keyboard overlays in landscape! a real mess...

Comment: Check the link, Facebook developers are tracking same issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1508038739461236/